# Testing a Node.js function whose return value can change depending upon the moment an asynchronous operation is permormed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, node.js, redis, jasmine

I am writing a mock for the [node-redis module](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine) to test it. I write tests for various aspects of Redis commands and my intention is to be able to run the tests against the original Redis module as well.

My problem is: *if I understood node-redis correctly*, the returned value of the asynchronous functions of node-redis is different depending upon the command was sent to Redis or queued for sending later (for example, to be sent after the connection is complete). But I would like to test the returned value, too, and if I write a test such as the one below:

```
it("should update value", function () {
  var client = redis.createClient();
  client.set("key", "1st");
  var value = client.get("key", function (err, data) {
    expect(err).toBeNull();
    expect(data).toBe("1st");
  });
  expect(value).toBe(true);
});
```

it will not pass if I use the real Redis module, because there will not be enough time to connect to database.

Is there a way to wait the asynchronous request to be executed to go ahead testing the code?

(Answers with different approaches to this problem are welcomed too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expect(err).toBeNull() == expect(value).toBe(true);` because asynchronous functions return nothing (undefined). You should do this only

```js
client.set("key", "1st");
client.get("key", function (err, data) {
  expect(err).toBeNull();
  expect(data).toBe("1st");
});
```

But if you want to wait you should use something like this:

```js
var value = undefined;
client.get("key", function (err, data) {
  expect(err).toBeNull();
  expect(data).toBe("1st");
  value = true;
});
setInterval(function(){ expect(value).toBe(true); }, 10000); // wait 10 seconds for connection
```

Comment: I agree with your fist point and would write my code this way. However, I am mocking a library, not write my own one. I am trying to emulate every aspect of the original API. I can eventually give up of simulating the return value but It is not my intention if I can get a solution for this.

Comment: Downvoting because it has nothing to do with OPs question, which is how to create a jasmine mock of a RedisClient/the redis module.